# Given the mean and the range of a normal distribution to find the variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, estimation, variance

I am wondering is it possible to estimate the variance based on the mean and the range (max, min) of a normal distribution. I only need an approximated result.

Comment: You apparently have a different definition of "range" than the usual one. If "range" means an interval that _almost_ all the distribution falls within, so there is very low probability of being outside that range, you would need to specify how close to zero is "very low." Different people could come up with a "range" of $3$ to $7,$ or $2$ to $8,$ or $1$ to $9,$ for the _exact same distribution,_ depending on what each of them thinks is "very low probability." It would help if you could point to some web page or quote some book where such a "range" is defined.

Comment: If you look at the "standard deviation" s wikipedia, there is a graph show the the bands of standard deviation. Most of the range are covered by 6 standard devoations.....so could I get take that as my range and estimate the standard deviation?

Comment: The variance is the square of the standard deviation, so if you define the range as six standard deviations, you divide by six and square. It's that simple. Of course one has to ask how you knew what six standard deviations would be if you didn't already know how much one standard deviation was.

Comment: I understand the ralation between std and variance. What i am a little bit confused is that   whether can i say the std is around the 1/6 of the "range" and what  this "range" covers the whole sample.....thx

Comment: Six standard deviations will almost _never_ match the range of a sample taken from a normally distributed population. It's still not completely clear what you're trying to do, but it is sounding more and more like a really bad idea.

Comment: Yep maybe I need to clarify my idea. I found something called  'Three Sigma Rule', which probably what I was looking for,,,,

Comment: Three sigmas is a useful heuristic if you already know the variance and want to guess what the next random value will be. If $99.7\%$ chance of a correct guess is good enough, "within $\pm3\sigma$" is a good guess. I do not consider this good enough for estimating the event "will not be hit by a car" when I cross the street, but it is good for many purposes. If you do not have some other way of estimating variance, three sigmas is nearly useless.

Answer (score 1):

The two parameters that specify a normal distribution are mean and variance. There is no such thing as a "range". Or, rather, there is: It's negative infinity to positive infinity. You can see that each of the distributions below have infinite range, so the question in its original form doesn't make much sense.

[image]

If you have samples from a distribution, the range will also be a pretty poor indicator of variance - you need the actual numbers. With a bunch of samples, you can calculate the variance with the standard statistics formula [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html).

Comment: I can see the point. In my case, the range is more like where the probability is close to zero. If I remember right, there is a figure to show the "range" can be measured by several sigmas....am I right?